# Unable to add Azure AD group with ':' in display name to Azure SQL, am I missing something?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

In our Azure AD, we have Security groups named with (:) in the name. So the format looks like `SG:{Group Name}`. When I try to add a group with (:) in the name to Azure SQL using a query below

```
CREATE USER [SG:Developers] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

I'm getting an error shown below

```
Msg 15007, Level 16, State 6, Line 1 'SG:Developers' is not a valid
login or you do not have permission.
```

I am able to add groups with spaces or underscores in the name, so far its just (:) causing issues.

[image]

I don't believe its permissions issue, cos I'm logged in to Azure SQL Database with Active Directory Admin credentials.

**EDIT**

As Alberto Morillo suggested in his answer, it could be true that (:) is the issue. But what I'm trying to understand is, why does it work without any issues when I add the same [SG:Developers] group as Active Directory Admin from Azure Portal, but doesn't work when trying to add it to any DB using a T-SQL statement. Whats the missing link?

Cross posted on [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e15d200e-b797-4879-a7f9-f3d6e481f867/unable-to-add-azure-ad-group-with-in-display-name-to-azure-sql-am-i-missing-something?forum=WindowsAzureAD#e15d200e-b797-4879-a7f9-f3d6e481f867)

Answer (score 2):

Names in Active Directory do  not allow colon (:) as mentioned in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and) support article.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "do not allow" cos as we can see in the screenshot above, group was created with no issues and is being used for many other purposes without problems. One of the working scenarios is assigning this group as Active Directory Admin from Azure Portal. Its not working only when trying to add from a T-SQL query.  

The article recommended doesn't talk about CNs, only OUs, computer, site and domain names. I could be wrong but, I believe Azure AD honors RFC 2253 for naming, which neither considers (:) as reserved character nor prevents the use of it.

Comment: I would not use any of the characters mentioned on the article, even when CNs are not named on the article. Many naming limitations on Azure are not documented.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, for the workaround and article, but can't accept it as answer. Because when I assign this very same group with (:) in name as Active Directory Admin from Azure Portal, it works fine. So I'm trying to know what is causing Azure SQL database to error while Azure Portal has no issues.

Comment: Let me share this on a Microsoft mail list and try to find someone that works on a team related to the topic.

Comment: Please run the following query to verify the login is not created already since you add the group as admin in the portal. SELECT * from master.sys.sql_logins will list logins for Azure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing with MS, Alberto!
I don't see the group under sys.sql_logins, but I do find it under sys.database_principals.

Comment: Then is already created, It seems then the error is misleading. That is the reason the statement is failing.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. When I add this group via Azure portal as AD Admin, it appears in database_principals. It disappears from there when I remove AD Admin from portal. When I try to add it from T-SQL its no where to be found, neither in sql_logins nor database_principals.

Comment: My fault. Let me share this and try to get a feedback.

Comment: No replies received yet. Sorry

Comment: No worries, I too switched to using underscores as a temporary(may be permanent) solution